# I would like to update a table with sets of results from another table without using multiple update statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How do I populate `tb_1` with a single statement without using multiple update statements in SQL Server? Then What if the BU has multiple segments, Consumer, Wholesale,etc & they all have the same set of products.

Let's say you have more than 10 products.

```
UPDATE tb_1
SET CurrYear = (SELECT SUM(CNT)
                FROM tb_2
                WHERE PRODUCT_GROUP IN ('Product1')
                AND SEGMENT Like 'Consumer%' ----(Consumer PP, Consumer Post)
WHERE Metric = 'Product1'
AND BU = 'Consumer'

--- here we add Product2

UPDATE tb_1
SET CurrYear = (SELECT SUM(CNT)
                FROM tb_2
                WHERE PRODUCT_GROUP IN ('Product2')
                AND SEGMENT IN ('Business', 'Retail'))
WHERE Metric = 'Product2'
AND BU = 'Enterprise'

----Here We Add Another Product for different Segments

UPDATE tb_1
SET CurrYear = (SELECT SUM(CNT)
                FROM tb_2
                WHERE PRODUCT_GROUP IN ('Product1')
                AND SEGMENT IN ('OLO', 'WS'))   ---Wholesale = (OLO + WS)
WHERE Metric = 'Product1
AND BU = 'Wholesale'
```

Comment: Careful when you edit your question; you removed all of the code formatting that was added.  It's much easier to read your question if the code snippets are wrapped in a code block; it preserves spacing, tabs and new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use query like this:

```
UPDATE tb_1
SET CurrYear = (
                SELECT SUM(CNT)
                FROM tb_2
                WHERE PRODUCT_GROUP = tb_1.Metric
                AND SEGMENT IN ('Business', 'Retail')
                )
WHERE BU = 'Enterprise'
    -- if you need to filter -- uncomment
    --AND Metric IN ('Product 1', 'Product 2')
```

You can use table name or alias from *UPDATE* statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use Common Table Expressions for brevity and improved readability.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT PRODUCT_GROUP, SUM(CNT) AS CNT
    FROM tb_2
    WHERE SEGMENT IN ('Business', 'Retail')
)
UPDATE tb_1 SET CurYear = cte.CNT
    FROM tb_1 INNER JOIN cte ON tb_1.Metric = cte.PRODUCT_GROUP
```